# VSTO - Recurring item popup status

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I have some schedual meetings with reccurence(with the property IsRecurring = 1) , when I want delete some meeting I get "Open reccuring item" popup, I want catch the status- if I want open just this one(1) or entire series(2).

[image]

Tried:

`currentExplorer.SelectionChange += new ExplorerEvents_10_SelectionChangeEventHandler(CurrentExplorer_Event); currentExplorer.ViewSwitch += new ExplorerEvents_10_ViewSwitchEventHandler(ViewSwitch_Event);`

This events not catch the selection status.
What is the best way to get this information?

Answer (score 1):

Track the `Inspectors.NewInspector` event. From there, you can use `Inspector.CurrentItem` property to access the `AppointmentItem` object. Read the `RecurrenceState` property - the possible values are `olApptOccurrence`, `olApptException`, `olApptMaster`, or `olApptNotRecurring`.

Comment: If i check status by olApptNotRecurring - it can give me indication that i select - just this one option ?

Comment: In that case the appointment is not a recurring appointment.

Comment: in case of `olApptNotRecurring`, you won't get the prompt from your screenshot. If you select "Just this one", you will get either `olApptOccurrence` or `olApptException`. In case of "The entire series", you will have `olApptMaster`. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to know which exactly is chosen on the dialog out of the box. The best what you could do is to handle the `NewInspector` event and check the [RecurrenceState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.recurrencestate) property which returns an `OlRecurrenceState` constant indicating the recurrence property of the specified object.

For the `Just this one` option the value should be `olApptOccurrence` which means the appointment is an occurrence of a recurring appointment defined by a master appointment.

In case of entire series you may find the appointment which is a master appointment (`olApptMaster`).